# positioning a div according to another div's position?

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to position a div according to another div with no avail!

I have a responsive full screen background site and on that there is a div called (logoholder) and within that logo holder there is another img holder which id-ed (logo) and it is responsive to user's screen resolution and device. this is done via jquery.

under the logo holder there are only 3 lines of paragraph (normal texts) which are also responsive as well. which means they will reduce/increase size on different screen resolutions. this is done via javascript.

Now, the problem is:

that when I look at the site on landscape screens, or portrait (i.e. iPhone, Samsung), the texts under the logo overlap on the logo or other way round.

I need to keep the texts/paragraph's positions according to the logo!

here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html
{
  font-size:100%;
}

#logo
{
  top:30%;
  height:auto;
  left:5%;
  position:absolute;
  width:38%;
  z-index:1000;
}

#txt1
{
  top:55%;
  height:auto;
  left:5%;
  position:absolute;
  width:55%;
  z-index:1000;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:100%;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin-top:4%;
}

#txt2
{
  top:59%;
  height:auto;
  left:5%;
  width:55%;
  z-index:1000;
  color:#cf0226;
  font-size:100%;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:4%;
}

#txt3
{
  top:63%;
  height:auto;
  left:5%;
  width:55%;
  z-index:1000;
  color:#cf0226;
  font-size:100%;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:4%;
}

#txt4
{
  top:22%;
  height:auto;
  left:5%;
  width:55%;
  z-index:1000;
  color:#cf0226;
  font-size:100%;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position:absolute;
}

#txt5
{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1000;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:4%;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
}

#logo img
{
  width:100%;
}

body
{
  background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat;
  font:16px/1.8 sans-serif;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin:0;
}

#preloader
{
  position:fixed;
  top:45%;
  left:50%;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-45px;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:-100px;
}

h1
{
  text-align:left;
  color:#fff;
  font:16px/1 "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a:hover
{
  color:#cf0226;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

#bottom
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:15px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:40px;
  text-align:center;
}

a:link,a:visited,a:active
{
  color:#cf0226;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

and this is the code from within body tags:

```
<div id="txt3" class="txt3">
    <h1 id="fittext3" style="font-weight:600;"><a href="#">No, I do not accept the site terms and conditions.</a></h1>
</div>
<div id="txt4">
    <h1 id="fittext4" style="font-weight:600; font-size:18px;">WELCOME TO</h1>
</div>
<div id="maximage">
    <img src="lib/images/demo/9mm_Vodka_Gun Solo_GRADED.jpg" alt="" width="1400" height="1050"/>
</div>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.maximage.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function(){
                // Trigger maximage
                jQuery('#maximage').maximage();
            });
        </script>
<!-- DON'T USE THIS: Insert Google Analytics code here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-733524-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
        </script>
</div>
<script src="fittext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      fitText(document.getElementById('fittext'), 3.5)
      fitText(document.getElementById('fittext2'), 3.6)
      fitText(document.getElementById('fittext3'), 3.6)
      fitText(document.getElementById('fittext4'), 3)
      fitText(document.getElementById('fittext5'),11.5)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should format your code nicely if you expect others to bother reading it.

Comment: @Diodeus, sorry, Done now.

Comment: That would take all day to understand that :S

Comment: It's still a mess. Fix the code in a text editor, then paste it in and press the CODE button "{}".

Comment: I just tried to Tidy that. Failed!!!

Comment: from what i seen while attempted tidy up you have alot of errors there 1st one beeing that you have no `<html>` tag

Comment: @Diodeus, sorry, i don't know why it creates such a mess when i paste the code in here! anyway, i pasted the CSS code and the code from body tags now.

Comment: @Connor, I do have <html></html> tags. just there was not enough room to paste the entire code here so i only pasted the necessary codes.

Comment: How come the `<!DOCTYPE>` is there then?

Comment: @Connor, Thanks. Right at the top of my document I have <!DOCTYPE html> and bellow that I have <html class='no-js' lang='en'> and right at the end of the document i have </html>. it was very strange that it was creating such a messy code when i was pasting it on here! I was only copying it from my dreamweaver!

Comment: @Connor I saw your edit and it was rejected (not by me). It looks like you re-added some html that was in his original question but that was not clear in the edit, so whoever reviewed it probably rejected it because of that.

Comment: @Paperjam i formatted the code but it was edited while i was editing...

Comment: This is barely possible to figure out what the problem is you need to provide something we can work with, i made a fiddle based on your code and here it is http://jsfiddle.net/4UaFw/